# Is it possible for JS running in a page in a web browser to move files on the host system's filesystem?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want be able to move files or folders using code from a website. As far as I know, it is possible with the OS, path, and fs modules of python or node.js. Is JavaScript running in a website able to manage files in a similar way? If this is not possible by default due to security issues, is there a way to enable it or work around that?

Comment: What is "the local folder"? How is this a problem related to CSS?

Comment: I'm sorry. This is my first time asking, but I tried to develop it as a web service, but it got stuck and I did this.

Comment: related, but not an answer: [Local file access with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/371875/11107541)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No duo to security reasons this is not possible, imagine you visit a website and suddenly the can delete/update/read all you files on the PC!

The only way to do this would be maybe via shell access to the users pc, but this is quite impossible!